# SQL Server, ServicerBroker for asynchronized execution of stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, service-broker

I followed this tutorial:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Using-Service-Broker-for-360c961a

and it is working for me,
However,
I don't understand some thing:
At `PROCEDURE proc_BrokerTargetActivProc` we have infinite loop: `WHILE (1=1)`. Why ? After all, during creating queue we bind messages with this procedure:`PROCEDURE_NAME = proc_BrokerTargetActivProc`.

In addition, I am not sure If I correctly understand way of working it:
`ExecuteProcedureAsync` push to queue message with name of procedure to execute.
What now ? How does it work that `BrokerTargetActivProc` will be called with exactly one message ?

What about parameter `MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 5` ?

Thank in advance,
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At PROCEDURE proc_BrokerTargetActivProc we have infinite loop: WHILE
>   (1=1). Why ?

The process for receiving messages in SQL Server requires what I call a semiactive polling. The code makes a request to the queue for the next message, then waits for a response. That is what the `WAITFOR` block is doing.

```
WAITFOR 
( RECEIVE TOP(1) 
    @RecvReqDlgHandle = conversation_handle, 
    @RecvReqMsg = message_body, 
    @RecvReqMsgName = message_type_name 
  FROM TASK_QUEUE 
), TIMEOUT 5000;
```

If the process was not in an infinite loop, the procedure would poll once, either receive a message or timeout, then quit. With the infinite loop, the procedure polls continuously until stopped.

> ExecuteProcedureAsync push to queue message with name of procedure to
>   execute. What now ? How does it work that BrokerTargetActivProc will
>   be called with exactly one message ?

When `ExecuteProcedureAsync` is called, it places the message in an asynchronous [message queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue). This is a process that is external to SQL Server, accepts messages from sending processes, and forwards them to the receiving process when it is ready for the next message (that is, when the receiver polls the queue for the next message on the queue). The reference to `BrokerTargetActiveProc` when putting the message on the queue is letting the queue know where the message is going. It is not an interrupt that triggers the BrokerTargetActiveProc procedure.

In an asynchronous queue like this, if the receiver is down, then the messages simply wait in the queue until the receiver comes back up or the queue runs out of resources to hold messages.

Comment: 1.Could you explain me, what are services here ? In reference to queue nad procedures.   2. Who execute `proc_BrokerTargetActivProc` procedure ? (which in real is infinite loop getting one message from queue).  3. What does it mean these parameters?: `@RecvReqDlgHandle = conversation_handle, `
`        @RecvReqMsg = message_body, `
`        @RecvReqMsgName `

Comment: 1) The Service Broker is the service used to manage the queues in this case. Other situations might use RabbitMQ or another external message queue handler.   2) In general: `proc_BrokerTargetActivProc` will either be activated by a SQL Server job, a startup procedure, or on the start of an application that needs the proc to handle messages. The exact startup mechanism depends on what you need and when you need it.

Comment: 3) [a] `conversation_handle` is a Service Broker UniqueIdentifier for the message queue, saved in the variable `@RecvReqDlgHandle`. [b] `message_body`is the actual message that was placed on the queue, saved in `@RecvReqMsg` for processing after it is pulled off of the queue. [c] `message_type_name` lets the receiving process understand what type of message was sent. As an example, if a message queue was set up to handle all inserts and updates to table Customers, the receiver needs to know if a given message was an Insert message or an Update message. This would be where that info was passed.

Comment: When it comes to above example (link) ? Who call `proc_BrokerTargetActivProc` ?

Comment: Is it difficult to call procedure with additional parameter?

Comment: And, from what `proc_BrokerTargetActivProc` know that it should get messages from `TASK_QUEUE`. In this procedure there is no this information

Comment: How to look into queue ?    Sorry for my dummy questions, but I am starting at this subject.

Comment: Ignore what I said above. When I reviewed the article and queue handling in Service broker, I realized that the key is in the `CREATE QUEUE` statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51541/discussion-between-laughing-vergil-and-haskell-fun).